# Java ArrayList inheritance problem (looks like a namespace collision)

Tags: java

I'm new to Java (three days spend actually), but I have to write a custom cross-platform editor app as an interface to my database. Everything is running smooth actually, but I've got a strange package error. inb4 3 years of Python and AS3 programming.

I'm trying to extend a **java.util.ArrayList** and got stucked into the **add** method overriding. Code looks somehow like that:

```
package myxmleditor;

public class BarsList<EditorXMLObject> extends 
    java.util.ArrayList<EditorXMLObject> {

@Override
public boolean add(EditorXMLObject element) {
    editorGUI.addEditorPane(element); // error here
    return super.add(element);
}

    public EditorGUIInterface editorGUI = null;
}
```

**BarsList**, **EditorGUIInterface** and **EditorXMLObject** are within the **myxmleditor** package. The addEditorPane method is

```
EditorGUIInterface.addEditorPane(EditorXMLObject element)
```

NetBeans shows me an error:

```
method addEditorPane in class myxmleditor.TsukasaXMLEditGUI cannot be applied to given types;
  required: **myxmleditor.EditorXMLObject**  
  found: **EditorXMLObject**  
  reason: actual argument EditorXMLObject cannot be converted to myxmleditor.EditorXMLObject by method invocation conversion
```

Comment: Can you provide some details about the `EditorGUIInterface` class? Especially it's `addEditorPane` method. Are all classes in the same package?

Comment: Solved by luckyjaca, I had to declare public class BarsList extends  java.util.ArrayList<EditorXMLObject> {

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class BarsList is not a template. If you would like to make BarsList a list of EditorXMLObject, simple write:

`public class BarsList extends java.util.ArrayList<EditorXMLObject>`

However if you would like to create another template basing on ArrayList, write:

`public class BarsList<T> extends java.util.ArrayList<T>`

Comment: +1 You were right, I was very wrong, good answer ... and I see now why was it not working.

Comment: There is actually a mistake in what I wrote. There should be `public class BarList<T> extends java.util.ArrayList<T>` without the first `<T>`

Answer (score 5):

It's probably best not to subclass ArrayList. Try keeping an ArrayList as a member of BarsList then calling the add yourself.

Using inheritance could make it more difficult to change list implementation at a later date (calling code could use ArrayList specific behaviour). Also, you are dependent on implementation details of ArrayList (as hertzsprung pointed out) and have become responsible for maintaining any contracts made by ArrayList. What should happen when the user calls remove, addAll or clear?

Alternatively, there is so little in the class, it might be easiest just to use the List directly and call addEditorPane manually. This depends on how often and where you call add from though.

Comment: You're saying that there is a general recommendation not to extend ArrayList? If he is indeed creating a new `List` implementation, I see no problem with extending ArrayList, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Why not to use the class inheritance when you need just to tweak one method a little.

Comment: Good questions, I've added some explanation, partly taken from hertzsprung's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing collections is dangerous because, for example, you don't know whether or not addAll() delegates to add() inside the superclass (this is explained further in [Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC&lpg=PA76&ots=U_K33qeH62&pg=PA71#v=onepage&q&f=false), p.71).

If you can avoid it, it would be better to create a forwarding collection; Google Guava's [ForwardingList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html) could be useful here.

Comment: Even if addAll() delegates to add() that's exactly what I need. Current code already worked with the ArrayList itself, but I had to make a class conversions and a type checks within an event-dispatching thread and it looked wierd for me. The simpliest solution to get rid of class conversions was to extend an ArrayList.

Comment: Nanako - what if it *doesn't* call add()? Then it will break if someone calls addAll. Also, what happens if someone removes an element?